# How to find messages where I'm the only recipient?

Tags: gmail, search, gmail-filters, mailing-list

I receive emails from a bunch of different mailing lists- how do I find emails that are sent only to me? I tried searching "Deliveredto: example@gmail.com" but it didn't bring up every email and also brought up a bunch that I sent.

I work in the media so I receive about 800 emails a day and unfortunately I can't unsubscribe from the lists.

Comment: have you tried `to:`, how's that working for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Let me first say that it appears that Gmail does not offer a straightforward way to do this.

Here is what you can *try*.

A.

1. On right end of "search box" there is a small down-pointing arrow.
2. `Left click` on it, and in `to`, put your email address.
3. `Left click` on "Create filter with this search".
4. Hit `Esc`.

This will show all emails sent to you.

Back to step 2, you can put to `-me`, or `me -*`, or `"example@gmail.com AND -*"` instead.

B.

If the senders aren't too many, *or* a big enough part of the receiving emails have multiple lists in common, you can:

Specifically exclude all other names on the mass mails in question.

In other words, if you get mail with a To line of
your...@you.com, "Jo Bloggs" , "Pat Smith"  ...

you can have a filter with a To field of
- "Jo Bloggs" -"Pat Smith" ...

etc.

Comment: @AlE what's wrong

Comment: Are you asking about my edit?

Comment: Yes. Was what I wrote against stack's rules?

Comment: Your answer should only contain your answer. It shouldn't contain greetings, or "thank you", or requests for votes, or requests for comments. This isn't a forum; we're building a knowledge base. More information at the [help/behavior].